# Low-Intensity Pulsed Ultrasonic (LIPUS) Circuit

Tags: ultrasound

I am trying to find a circuit schematic of a device that can create ultrasound wave frequencies of 1-3 MHz and deliver intensities of 2 - 30 mW/cm^2. I am on a Summer research project and need to know if this is feasible to create within a 3-5 week period. We are primarily concerned with focusing the ultrasound with phononic crystals, so the LIPUS device is not the main concern, it simply needs to make the waves. We are trying to get the device commercially, but since this is an eight-week program and I am the electrical engineering student, I have been tasked with finding a circuit if possible. It is very difficult to find this anywhere as many existing devices are proprietary and it is an understudied field. However, the underlying mechanism seems pretty simple.

The device should be portable, so I know I will need a DC-DC converter to create a high voltage to drive the low impedance transducer. Initially it will not need to be pulsed as I am sure I can add that functionality later with a digital solution.

[[image: 1]X. Jiang, W. T. Ng, and J. Chen, “A Miniaturized Low-Intensity Ultrasound Device for Wearable Medical Therapeutic Applications,” IEEE Trans. Biomed. Circuits Syst., vol. 13, no. 6, pp. 1372–1382, Dec. 2019, doi: 10.1109/TBCAS.2019.2947395.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJfC9.png)

This above image is a circuit we are trying to replicate, but we obviously cannot make an ASIC in time. Miniaturization is not important here, just functionality. I'd like to simply use discrete components. Any recommendations?

Comment: *I am on a Summer research project and need to know if this is feasible to create within a 3-5 week period* That sounds ambitious, just because we're living in the Chipocalypse and some components are hard to get.

Comment: 1MHz therapeutic massage wands can do much more than this for $80 delivered in days. $120 even more

Comment: "It is an understudied field": Um, I'm 100% sure the physiological effects of sound in the image-giving ultrasonic range is *more* than studied. Like, seriously. We do this to pregnant women, a lot, for example; if anything is exhaustively investigated, it's probably that.  Also, 149 studies that were actually included in a current survey paper *Low-Intensity Continuous Ultrasound Therapies—A Systemic
Review of Current State-of-the-Art and Future Perspectives* that doesn't sound like "underresearched" at all.

Comment: I have one that is 1MHz modulated for better effects. Low power but not battery operated. they work really well ,same thing Chiro’s use.  It this is Measurement results show that a maximum output voltage of 14 V is achieved by the proposed fully-integrated DC-DC boost converter with a battery supply voltage of 3.7 V. 105 mW

Comment: Can you use a function generator? You can make a simple amplifier if you need higher voltage (drive a transformer).

Comment: @MarcusMüller , chipocalypse is a good way to describe it.

Comment: Marcus Müller, I know that imaging ultrasound is very studied, I should have elaborated more. This type of ultrasound is for healing purposes, specifically for bone fractures. The main difference in this ultrasound being the applied intensity (W/cm^2) being much lower than that for imaging. There are only a handful of devices that exist on the market for this purpose. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-intensity_pulsed_ultrasound